# Hub sites permissions inheritance

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, hub-site

I've seen a demo with the following screenshot :
[image]

It shows that you can enable permission synchronisation between a hub site and its associated sites.

I am not able to find this feature on my own tenant. 
Is it because it's a demo feature ? If so is there a roadmap for general availabilty ?
Or should I activate something to access this feature ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is not available, yet. What you're looking at is a Microsoft demo tenant to show features that will be rolling out in the future. This was announced at Ignite 2019.

[The intelligent intranet powered by Microsoft 365 – Microsoft Ignite 2019 announcements](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sharepoint-blog/the-intelligent-intranet-powered-by-microsoft-365-microsoft/ba-p/975037)